# spring-cloud-stream-kafka not honoring single consumer for a group

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am using *spring-cloud-stream-kafka*. I am starting 2 instances of a consumer application with the same group name **testGroup** consuming messages from a Kafka topic **testTopic** with single partition, I expected one of the consumer instances to consume messages from the Kafka topic and the other instance to not consume anything since they share the same group name. I am using *0.8.xx version of Kafka client*. Here are my properties

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=testTopic

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=testGroup
```

Any idea what could be happening ?

Answer (score 1):

Right, that is the expected behaviour for 1.0.3/ 0.8 where we use the SimpleConsumer API. You don't need to do that after 1.1 - see http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/1.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_instance_index_and_instance_count for details.

Comment: Does this mean that I cannot have a TOPIC with single partition and have 2 consumers instances with same group pointing to it and have only one instance be consuming messages. I needed to setup more than 1 consumer instance for resiliency

Comment: No, it means that you need to follow the instructions in the link and configure instance index and instance count accordingly for each running instance.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Spring Cloud Stream are you using? 
I think you are using `1.0.3` version of Spring Cloud Stream which supports Kafka `0.8.xx` version. Anyway, this looks like a bug.

Also, I don't see this issue when using Kafka 0.9 or 0.10 with Spring Cloud Stream 1.1.x.

Comment: I am using Brixton.SR6 which pulls
 spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka (1.0.2.RELEASE)